# How can I obtain crystal-clear glycerin?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I'm trying to get perfect crystal clear glycerin for my experiments with decorative soap. Is there a special way to get it or should I buy a special formula of it? I have not succeeded in purifying the glycerin I have to more than a milky-translucent, semi-transparent soap.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy high-purity glycerin from numerous vendors online. High-purity grades will be as crystal-clear as you can possibly get.

For instance, check out the [premium grade glycerin product from Sigma-Aldrich](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sial/g2289?lang=en&region=US&cm_sp=Insite-_-prodRecCold_xviews-_-prodRecCold10-5) which should be suitable for your needs but is quite expensive.

There are less expensive (but pure enough for your needs) options, so be sure to explore the other grades available from other vendors. For example, you can secure [a gallon of Kosher USP food grade vegetable-derived glycerin for $14.99 from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00PSGWHIO). This product (or similar) is adequate for your needs at a better price point that lab-grade reagents.

Comment: @orrachevsky - I'm amended my answer to include an option that is probably best for you. It pays to shop around, and you can get a gallon of glycerin (USP food grade, vegetable-derived and Kosher) for $14.99 from Amazon (see link in my answer, above). Good luck!